Keyboard shortcut to split screen
There are some questions related to this but all are outdated. Can someone tell me how to split the screen in a single display for two active applications? Only using the keyboard (doing it with the cursor is just too annoying in my opinion)
Thank you!

What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Have you tried super (Windows key) + left arrow/right arrow

This can be achieved using only the keyboard as follows in two simple steps:

Use Alt + tab to focus on a window that needs to be split.
Press Shift + right/left arrow key to split the focused window

If you want to resize the windows:

Press Alt + F8 to enable resize mode then use the arrow keys to resize the windows.
Press the Esc or the Enter key to get out of the resize mode

reference It's FOSS
